# Filter Pixels in Image by Color Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, apple-vision

My project is using Vision to identify a certain rectangle in the field of view. I know this rectangle will be of a certain color. In OpenCV, there is a filter that allows you to filter pixels out by color, as seen [here](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/05/08/detect-red-circles-image-using-opencv/).

I am new to the CoreImage framework, but I couldn't see any filters that would accomplish this goal. Is there some kind of built-in filter (it doesn't necessarily have to be in CoreImage) for this, or do I need to learn how to write my own?

Comment: I don't *think* there's a built-in filter for this (and absolutely, I could be wrong). Based on your linked example, I think something like `CIColorCube` won't come close to what you want. But building a simple `CIColorKernel` might do the trick. Pass it an input color (and if you need an ROI, make it a `CIKernel`) you could (a) recognize the *exact* color you are looking for and (b) have a "region of interest" or ROI. Are you looking the have similar output as your link? (Black unless it's the color *and* within the ROI?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Goal**

What I can understand from the information under the given link, you would like to filter red areas to white and all other areas to black.

For that a CIColorKernel could be used.

**CIColorKernel**

> A GPU-based image processing routine that processes only the color information in images, used to create custom Core Image filters.

see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicolorkernel

**Screenshot**

Here a screenshot with an ugly background color to see areas covered by the images better.

[image]

In the upper area the input image is shown. In the lower area the resulting image is displayed.

**Source**

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var upperImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lowerImageView: UIImageView!


    let kernelString =
        """
        kernel vec4 thresholdFilter(__sample textureColor) {

            if (textureColor.r > 0.8 && textureColor.g < 0.1 && textureColor.b < 0.1) {
                textureColor.rgb = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            } else {
                textureColor.rgb = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            }

            return textureColor;
        }
        """

    let kernel: CIColorKernel

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.kernel = CIColorKernel(source: kernelString)!
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.upperImageView.image = UIImage(named: "example.png")
    }


    @IBAction func onFilter(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let inputImage = upperImageView.image else { return }
        guard let ciInputImage = CIImage(image: inputImage) else { return }

        let ciImageFiltered = self.kernel.apply(
            extent: ciInputImage.extent,
            arguments: [ciInputImage])

        let filteredImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImageFiltered!)
        self.lowerImageView.image = filteredImage
    }
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your descriptive answer! Is there any way to do this with HSV as well, or only RGB?

Comment: Perhaps a starting point: in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50569196/2331445 I link some HSL routines (not written by me).